# Trouble getting next line of a file in Java using the Scanner class

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get a nextLine call but seem to be getting the rest of the entire file when I make it.

```
header = getHeaderLine(fname, columns);

Scanner inputFile = null;

try{
    inputFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fname));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File is not found.");
    System.exit(0);
}

if (hasHeader) inputFile.nextLine();

String line = inputFile.nextLine();

for(int i=0; i<body.length; i++){
    body[i] = getEntries(line, columns);
    line = inputFile.nextLine();
}
```

Here where I call for the nextLine() it seems to grab the entire rest of the file.
This is the error I'm gedtting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at CFR.main(CFR.java:50)
```

Comment: Check if you have next line before getting it with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think it's running through the file and trying to grab the next line once I've already reached the end of the file. I need to change my stop condition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with the `end-of-line` character.  The end of line character varies between various operating systems linux, mac, windows/DOS etc.

Check if the file has the right `end-of-line` character for the OS you are running on.